# How do I use "-optimize" with dotnet cli?

Tags: c#, .net-core, compiler-options

Up until now I've been using *csc.exe* from *.NET Framework* to compile my short C# scripts. Nothing too fancy, I just wanted to explore a bit and the *csc.exe* was already on my computer. Now that I'm trying to write my projects using the *.NET Core sdk* (which I found here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1), I am not sure how to specify those classic compiler options such as "-optimize".

I am aware that I don't really need "-optimize", but I would still like to experiment and maybe use some other options that I haven't considered yet. The only solution that I came up with was using the provided *csc.dll* (using "dotnet <path>/csc.dll ...") which meant going full circle back to *csc.exe* which kind of defeated the purpose of the whole sdk.

How to reproduce this situation:

- new folder
- "dotnet new console"
- all nececery files are now generated ("Project.csproj", "Program.cs", "bin/", "obj/...")
- "dotnet run"
- what now?

I assume I need to add something to the .csproj file since it has "`<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>`" for "-unsafe" however, I haven't found anything for "-optimize".

Additional info:
Im using *Visual Studio Code*, which I don't think is relevant for this problem, but just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling for "release" automatically turn that option on. To use that, pass `-c Release` to the `dotnet` command.

For example, `Release` points to a configuration that looks something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);RELEASE;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
</PropertyGroup>
```

More information [here](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2017/04/24/creating-custom-build-configurations-for-the-dotnet-core-project-format/).

Comment: Omg yes, I was looking for "\<Optimize\>true\</Optimize\>" thank you. I somehow didn't find it in the docs so I assumed it didn't exist. I just tried it with a quick performance test (on a debug build) and the difference between true and false is astronomical (*for the test I made).